# storage account is not deleted forever

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have created VM on Azure and found wrong named storage then.

VM: hanpohwan,
storage: hanpohwa (truncated name, automatically created)

I deleted the VM but the storage is not deleted forever. How do you solve this problem now?

hanpohwan-hanpohwan-os-1462083556580.vhd    127.00 GB   2016-05-01 오전 7:47:59   application/octet-stream    https://hanpohwa.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/hanpohwan-hanpohwan-os-1462083556580.vhd

Error message is:

Microsoft Azure operation failed.
The remote server returned an error: (412) There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request..
The remote server returned an error: (412) There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request..

Learn more about known storage blob issues and solutions at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=532762.

Answer (score 1):

With the classic (ASM) deployment model in Azure, VHDs need to be configured as "Disks" before they can be attached to a VM. This configuration takes a permanent lease on the VHD and ensures that the VHD is made visible in the Disks tab of the Virtual Machines section on the classic portal. You will need to delete this Disk in the portal (or PowerShell or CLI). This action will optionally also delete the VHD. Once you do that there will no longer be a lease on the VHD and you will be able to delete the storage account.

Comment: Thanks guys. There is neither os-disk nor vhd searched in azure portal. So I checked CLI and found problem vm disk and 'azure vm disk delete ---' it.